# Sampling a uniformly random satisfying assignment

Tags: np-hardness, counting-complexity, reductions

> **Problem:** Given $\phi : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ represented by a boolean circuit, generate a uniformly random $x \in \{0,1\}^n$ such that $\phi(x)=1$ (or output $\perp$ if no such $x$ exists).

Clearly this problem is NP-hard. My question is whether or not this problem is also "NP-easy":

> **Question:** Does there exist an algorithm that solves the above problem in time polynomial in $n$ and the circuit size of $\phi$ given access to a SAT oracle?

Alternatively, is there a polynomial-time algorithm assuming NP=P?

Clearly having access to a #SAT oracle suffices, so the complexity lies somewhere between NP and #P.

---

I feel like this should have been studied before, but I can't find an answer on Google.

I know how to solve the problem approximately (i.e. generate a satisfying assignment that is statistically close to uniform) using a variant of the Valiant-Vazirani Theorem and/or approximate counting, but getting exactly uniform seems to be a different problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Yes.](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/ug.html)

(backup links in case that one goes down: [1](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PSX/bgp.pdf) [2](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.5.89) [3](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/233577045_Uniform_Generation_of_NP-Witnesses_Using_an_NP-Oracle) [4](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540100928852))

Back up reference, in case all those links go down: Bellare, Mihir, Oded Goldreich, and Erez Petrank. "Uniform generation of NP-witnesses using an NP-oracle." Information and Computation 163.2 (2000): 510-526.